# How do I fix this multiple builds in TestFlight (iTunes Connect) bug?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I've been trying to fix an odd issue for two days now. After thinking something was messed up with the developer certificates or profiles, then starting from complete scratch and signing all new certs/profiles, I'm convinced this is either:

- A: TestFlight / iTunes Connect Bug
- B: Xcode bug in El Capitan
- C: A messed up Xcode project configuration

**Product Versions:**
**Mac OS X El Capitan:** *10.11.3 (15D21)*
**Xcode:** *7.2.1 (7C1002)*

**Here's what's happening:**

When trying to upload an App to `TestFlight` the build appears to get uploaded twice. Once the processing completes, the later build succeeds while the previous build stays in `Processing` stage indefinitely. I've used `Xcode Archive tool` and the `Application Loader` with the same result. Doesn't make a difference.

Under the `Internal Testing` section; The later of the builds is not even listed. The previous build is still unselectable as it's stuck in the `Processing` stage.

I receive no emails about build failures or otherwise.

In fact, I get a success email from Apple:

```
Dear XXX,
The following build has completed processing:

Platform: iOS
App Name: XXX
Build Number: 1.1
Version Number: 0.2.4
App SKU: XXX
App Apple ID: XXX

You can now use this build for TestFlight testing or submit it to the App Store.
```

**Please see the images for more information.**

[image: iOS Builds]

[image: External Testing > Select Version]

Comment: I think its apple website bug,, may be it will resolve automatically after some time. Or you may repot it to apple as well.

Comment: We have the same problem, still looking for a fix :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your application build number is hardcoded to 1.1. Check your info.plist file:

- CFBundleShortVersionString is for version number
- CFBundleVersion is for build number

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the build number would affect this? As far as I'm aware, that's what the internal TestFlight version numbers are used for - keeping us from increasing the external build numbers. Changing the build number also doesn't solve this issue. So again, asking for clarification.

Comment: As far as I know the build number comes from uploaded app, didn't know about "internal TestFlight version numbers". Have to check, thanx! In our case we're manually (script) setting build number, otherwise got upload error. We also use build numbers to map CI releases to version control, so we never had this problem.